# Safari not opening a href with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, safari

Safari ignores the a href link. Other browsers pass the countClicks function AND pass the link to open the new browser window. Any suggestions?

The JavaScript source is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function        countClicks(enterprise_code,sid_code,buspart_id,prod_id,server_name,path_info,query_string)
    {
    window.location.href = "/sharedInc/cf/polTrack.cfm?Buspart_id=" + buspart_id + "&Enterprise_Code=" + enterprise_code + "&Sid_Code=" + sid_code  + "&Prod_id=" + prod_id + "&Server_Name=" + server_name + "&Path_Info=" + path_info + "&Query_String=" + query_string;
    }
</script>
```

Whereas the HTML markup is:

```
<a href="http://www.polclients.com" target="_blank" onclick="countClicks('POL','POL',6808,387,'www.princetonol.com','/index.cfm','x=x&at=no')">Link</a>
```

Comment: tried "location.href" without the "window" part? Else try inserting an alert("hello"); or whatever inside the function to see if it even gets a call. Best regards Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with either `document.location.href` or just `location.href` .

Hey there. Your code should work. Well i tried this simple example on Safari browser and it works good. Try yourself.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function countClicks()
         { 
           window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
         }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad=countClicks()>
</body>
</html>
```

**Anchor Property :** FYI : I have used `window.open`

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function countClicks()
     { 
      window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "_blank");
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" name="xy" onclick="javascript:countClicks(this);">Visit StackOverflow Website</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Passing variables from function**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function countClicks(a,b)
    { 
       window.open("http://stackoverflow.com?id="+a+"&id2="+b, "_blank");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" name="xy" onclick="javascript:countClicks(2,3);">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the url from **href** and pass the url to the function which you are calling on **onclick**.
Inside this function, you can simply use window.open(your_url) to open the link in new tab.
So, this will solve your problem.
Here is the sample :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function countClicks(enterprise_code,sid_code,buspart_id,prod_id,server_name,path_info,query_string,new_site_url)
{
    window.open(new_site_url);
    window.location.href = "/sharedInc/cf/polTrack.cfm?Buspart_id=" + buspart_id + "&Enterprise_Code=" + enterprise_code + "&Sid_Code=" + sid_code  + "&Prod_id=" + prod_id + "&Server_Name=" + server_name + "&Path_Info=" + path_info + "&Query_String=" + query_string;
}
```

and here is your anchor tag :

```
< a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="countClicks('POL','POL',6808,387,'www.princetonol.com','/index.cfm','x=x&at=no','http://www.polclients.com')">Link< /a>
```

So, this code will open a new tab (with the url you provide) 
and after opening the tab, window.location will work as usual.
Hope, this will help you.

Comment: The problem of this code is thet the opened window with new address can be blocked by popup blockers